# Computer Software - Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How to put remark in separate column for giving date range. e.g. I have various dates in column A and want following answer in column B i.e.

- If date >= 01/04/2017 and <= 30/06/2017 answer should be Q1
- If date >= 01/07/2017 and <= 30/09/2017 answer should be Q2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First create a small lookup table in columns **C** through **E**:

[image]

where **E1** contains the formula:

```
=Q1
```

Then in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",VLOOKUP(A1,C$1:E$11,3,TRUE))
```

and copy down.  Then enter your dates in column **A**:

[image]

**NOTE:**

- column **D** is only there for visual purposes; it is not required by the formulas.

Comment: @ChrisRogers  **You are correct.**  The lookup table can be extended indefinitely.  I like your approach better.

Comment: Hmmmm....an indefinite lookup table....that is curious.  Out of interest and with respect, how would that work practicably?  Your approach is not necessarily wrong.  In fact it's clever.  It's just the finite situation.

Comment: @ChrisRogers  It is up to the user.  If the user is only interested in several years in the future, then I would make the table down to say 2060.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I tried and failed to construct a formula that calculates the Q-number by formula directly from the date........it gave me a migraine.

Answer (score 1):

---

The answer to your question depends on your **full** requirements.

The answer by @Gary'sStudent will help if the Q number increases every 3 months no matter what the year, (going to Q5, Q6, Q7 ...).  The only thing is the range of dates it can handle is finite.

You could improve this (as shown below).  Both work, it just depends on what method you wish to use.

If what I suspect, which is not made explict in your question, is that you wish to go from Q1 to Q4 and then back to Q1, representing financial quarters of the year, I have a second approach also shown below.

---

### Indefinite range version of answer provided by @Gary'sStudent

Let's go through this in stages....

Let's start by entering the dates in **Column A** @Gary'sStudent provided for testing purposes.

[image: Dates provided by Gary'sStudent]

We need to start by finding out the start of quarter 1 for the year of the first date entered.  The formula needed for this is:

```
=IF(MONTH(MIN(A:A))>=4,DATE(YEAR(MIN(A:A)),4,1),DATE(YEAR(MIN(A:A))-1,4,1))
```

Put this in **Cell D1** for now.

Now we need to work out the number of quarters (3 monthly intervals) between the start date in **cell D1** and the date in **cell A1**

For this we need `=ROUNDDOWN((DATEDIF($D$1,A1,"M"))/3,0)` (Number of Months divided by 3 - Rounded down)

Enter this in **Cell B1**

Then we need to add "Q" at the beginning and add 1 to give us the Q number.

```
="Q"&ROUNDDOWN((DATEDIF($D$1,A1,"M"))/3,0)+1
```

Now you can substitute `$D$1` for the formula in **cell D1**.  Formula in **cell B1** is now

```
="Q"&ROUNDDOWN((DATEDIF(IF(MONTH(MIN(A:A))>=4,DATE(YEAR(MIN(A:A)),4,1),DATE(YEAR(MIN(A:A))-1,4,1)),A1,"M"))/3,0)+1
```

You can then clear **cell D1**

### To give you the number of the financial quarter within the year for a given date (Q1 to Q4 then Q1) you need nested IF() statements.  Do this in steps or it will be complex.

#### *****Step 1*****

For testing purposes, produce a list of dates at the first of every month in **Column A**

In cell **B1** enter the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",A1=" "),"",IF(AND(MONTH(A1)>3,MONTH(A1)<7),"Q1",""))
```

If you should get "Q1" in cell **B1**, and grabbing the bottom right handle of the cell and dragging it down will paste the progressive formula into the cells below with a result of giving Q1 where the date is in financial quarter 1 and leaving the others blank.

[image: image of the progress so far]

#### *****Explanation of the formula*****

The first `IF()` statement is

```
IF(OR(A1="",A1=" "),"",.....)
```

This checks for nothing **or a space** in cell **A1** first.  If there is, we don't want a Q number.

The second part of the first `IF()` statement (the ..... bit above) is the second `IF()` statement which is

```
IF(AND(MONTH(A1)>3,MONTH(A1)<7),"Q1","")
```

Which checks that the month of the date in cell **A1** is greater than 3 (after March) and less than 7 (before July).  If it is, the formula wil enter **"Q1"** into cell **B2**

#### *****Step 2*****

To give quarter 2, you need to copy the second **IF()** statement and paste it over the double quotes at the end of the formula in cell **B1**, then amend the new portion to suit.  (checking for month > 6 and < 10 to give "Q2")

This will mean that in cell B2 you will have;

`=IF(OR(A1="",A1=" "),"",IF(AND(MONTH(A1)>3,MONTH(A1)<7),"Q1",IF(AND(MONTH(A1)>6,MONTH(A1)<10),"Q2","")))`

You can prove this works again by doing what you did before and drag the formua down over the cells below.

#### *****Step 3*****

Keep going for the other quarters except for Q3, you only need `IF(MONTH(A1)>9,"Q3","")`

The resulting formula at the end will be;

```
=IF(OR(A1="",A1=" "),"",IF(AND(MONTH(A1)>3,MONTH(A1)<7),"Q1",IF(AND(MONTH(A1)>6,MONTH(A1)<10),"Q2",IF(MONTH(A1)>9,"Q3",IF(AND(MONTH(A1)>0,MONTH(A1)<4),"Q4","")))))
```

and dragging the formula down the remainder of the cells will give you the following

[image: final result]

Comment: A very nice approach!